# set classes with a loop based on a Id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a regular image slider with a menu that slides with it.

if the slider is on slide #3 the menu will look like this: (this is menu buttons with the slide Id)

```
3 4 5 1 2
```

The current slide is always first and the next is the next slide and the first slide is after the last one.

so if slide #4 is current the menu would look like this:

```
4 5 1 2 3
```

And now I want to set a class to each of these. So the first in order have a class like "position1" and the next "position2" etc.

This function is called on every slide change and the variable currentSlide contains the currentSlide id.

```
function setMenuColors(currentSlide) {
    jQuery('#slider-menu'+currentSlide).removeClass().addClass('slider-menu-item position1');
}
```

after that jquery stuff that sets the class for the current slide a loop of some sort should set the class for the next four slides but I cant figure out how I should do it.

Anyone got any ideas?

Edit: The HTML for the menu looks like this:

```
<ul id="slider-menu-content">
    <li id="slider-menu1" class="slider-menu-item position1">slide menu button 1</li>
    <li id="slider-menu2" class="slider-menu-item position2">slide menu button 2</li>
    <li id="slider-menu3" class="slider-menu-item position3">slide menu button 3</li>
    <li id="slider-menu4" class="slider-menu-item position4">slide menu button 4</li>
    <li id="slider-menu5" class="slider-menu-item position5">slide menu button 5</li>
    <li id="slider-menu1" class="slider-menu-item position1">slide menu button 1</li>
    <li id="slider-menu2" class="slider-menu-item position2">slide menu button 2</li>
    <li id="slider-menu3" class="slider-menu-item position3">slide menu button 3</li>
    <li id="slider-menu4" class="slider-menu-item position4">slide menu button 4</li>
    <li id="slider-menu5" class="slider-menu-item position5">slide menu button 5</li>
</ul>
```

The doublets is created by jQuery so that the menu can loop seamlessly.
The order of the elements does not change.

Answer (score 0):

Imagining that you have a structure like:

```
<div id="container">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
   <div>5</div>
</div>
```

You can

```
$("#container").children("div").removeClass().addClass("slider-menu-item");
$("#container").children("div :first").addClass("first");
```

See for instance:
http://jsfiddle.net/VAMhu/

Comment: The problem is that I want to add a class to all elements. And the order of the elements in the container does not change. (since its the container that moves and not the elements within it.)

Comment: I am not getting the point here. if you have some set child elements in a container then the above code given by @nico should work for you. Can you explain what part is not working for you.

Comment: That code will only add class for the first slide. I need to have a class for each slide. And the first element in the container is not always the current slide.

Comment: @Patrik: the above code applies the `slider-menu-item` class to each slide (see the jsFiddle example, they have yellow background), then it applies the `first` style to the first child div. I don't understand when you say that the first element is not always the current... for instance you say that if 4 is selected then the order is `4 5 1 2 3` (hence 4 is the first element). What am I missing?